# Bluemix Analytics for cordova app : My Analytics service won't receive any data (logs, etc. )

Tags: cordova, ibm-cloud, analytics, ibm-mobile-services

I'm trying to implement the service Mobile Analytics from the IBM Bluemix Enviroment into my cordova app, which is a hyprid (app and browser). After following the guide provided by IBM : (https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/mobileanalytics/index.html#getting-started-with-mobile-analytics)
But even if follow the cordova guide mentioned in that link and provide with the needed information like api-key and all that , it still wont send any type of information like login activity or userdata. (Yes , i tried that while I was logged in as an user and tried clicking different buttons to test if the analytics service receives the data) . All this code is inserted in my cordova.js or component.js (tried both) which are the main cordova files in my root. I tried to debug the code with visual studio but all the methods are imported and seem to work well(after I installed the plugin of course). I really don't know what went wrong . Is there anything that can block my data in windows10 or did I miss something? Any help will be appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: What platform are you not receiving data with -- Android or iOS?

Comment: Hello Joe! I only tried with the web browser. But has to work both on iOS, Android and Web browsers.

Comment: As far as I know, there is not a Mobile Analytics Client SDK for Web browsers. I cannot find documentation about this. I do know about the Android and iOS SDKs (and the Cordova one which bridges to each of those).

Comment: Okay. But I still launch my app on windows 10 at least, as a win10 app. But I dont get any data which I can observe on my Mobile analytics service.

Comment: The Cordova SDK is a wrapper around the iOS and Android SDKs. If you aren't using those platforms, then the code is not going to be executed as far as I know. I do not have a Windows machine to recreate your issue. You may consider opening up a support ticket if you need further assistance.